# SagePay: 3014 : The TxType or PaymentType is invalid (REPEAT)

Tags: php, payment, repeat, opayo

I have an issue with repeating transactions on SagePay. Support said that they enable it for me (on test account) but can't get any other response from their support either.

Anyway. I'm using SERVER integration and SagePay library for it.

I'm succeed to pass the payment but when trying to REPEAT it's failed.

Here's what I'm sending:

```
array(42) {
    ["VPSProtocol"]=>
  string(4) "3.00"
    ["TxType"]=>
  string(6) "REPEAT"
    ["Vendor"]=>
  string(15) "vendor_name"
    ["VendorTxCode"]=>
  string(27) "REPEAT-1464105247-000000000"
    ["Amount"]=>
  string(6) "155.36"
    ["Currency"]=>
  string(3) "GBP"
    ["Description"]=>
  string(42) "Description"
    ["NotificationURL"]=>
  string(66) "http://example.com/sagepay_notification/"
    ["BillingSurname"]=>
  string(6) "Surname"
    ["BillingFirstnames"]=>
  string(6) "Firstname"
    ["BillingAddress1"]=>
  string(22) "First line address"
    ["BillingCity"]=>
  string(7) "City"
    ["BillingPostCode"]=>
  string(7) "PostCode"
    ["BillingCountry"]=>
  string(2) "GB"
    ["DeliverySurname"]=>
  string(6) "Surname"
    ["DeliveryFirstnames"]=>
  string(6) "Firstname"
    ["DeliveryAddress1"]=>
  string(22) "First line address"
    ["DeliveryCity"]=>
  string(7) "City"
    ["DeliveryPostCode"]=>
  string(7) "PostCode"
    ["DeliveryCountry"]=>
  string(2) "GB"
    ["StoreToken"]=>
  int(1)
  ["CustomerName"]=>
  string(13) "Firstname Lastname"
    ["CustomerEMail"]=>
  string(0) ""
    ["VendorEMail"]=>
  string(0) ""
    ["SendEMail"]=>
  int(0)
  ["eMailMessage"]=>
  string(0) ""
    ["BillingAddress2"]=>
  string(11) "Town Centre"
    ["BillingPhone"]=>
  string(11) "07000000000"
    ["ApplyAVSCV2"]=>
  int(0)
  ["Apply3DSecure"]=>
  int(0)
  ["AllowGiftAid"]=>
  int(1)
  ["BillingAgreement"]=>
  int(1)
  ["RelatedVPSTxId"]=>
  string(38) "{00000C44-0000-0000-0000-849C140E0000}"
    ["RelatedVendorTxCode"]=>
  string(28) "PAYMENT-1463754864-000000000"
    ["RelatedSecurityKey"]=>
  string(10) "LPSS900000"
    ["RelatedTxAuthNo"]=>
  string(8) "109700000"
    ["DeliveryAddress2"]=>
  string(11) "Town Centre"
    ["DeliveryPhone"]=>
  string(11) "0700000000"
    ["BasketXML"]=>
  string(300) "Installment1155.360.00155.36155.36"
    ["SurchargeXML"]=>
  string(175) "MC5VISA3.5"
    ["Profile"]=>
  string(6) "NORMAL"
    ["AccountType"]=>
  string(1) "E"
}
```

And here's my response:

```
array(3) {
  ["VPSProtocol"]=>
  string(4) "3.00"
  ["Status"]=>
  string(7) "INVALID"
  ["StatusDetail"]=>
  string(44) "3014 : The TxType or PaymentType is invalid."
}
```

Any ideas why I still have that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sorted it out.

The issue was that I didn't notice that repeat payments have to be send on different URL address.

> REPEAT / REPEATDEFERRED TEST
>   https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/repeat.vsp REPEAT /
>   REPEATDEFERRED LIVE
>   https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/repeat.vsp